# Best hash-algorithm

Tags: hash

What is the most secure hash-algorithm.
Can you also give the second best and the third best like this:
1. Test
2. test
3. TEST
I dont care about the performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing the security of different algorithms isn't easy. But I think the following algorithms would all be fine choices:

- **SHA-3 / Keccak** especially with large capacity (say 1024 bits)

  The biggest problem with this suggestion is that NIST hasn't finalized the SHA-3 specification yet.
- **BLAKE**

  A SHA-3 finalist, which some people (including myself) preferred BLAKE over Keccak.

  NIST praised it for its high security, but ultimately chose Keccak over BLAKE. As I understood it, NIST's main reason for that choice was that Keccak differs more from SHA-2, minimizing the chance that *both* SHA-3 and SHA-2 get broken.
- **SHA-2**, preferably **SHA-512**

  The security margin is a bit lower than the margin for Keccak or BLAKE, but it has remained unbroken for a long time and is widely implemented.
- **Skein**

  Another SHA-3 finalist. My impression during the SHA-3 competition was that programmers liked Skein best, due to Bruce Schneier's fame, the well written paper describing it, the additional features and high performance in software. Cryptographers on the other hand seemed to prefer BLAKE or Keccak over Skein.

For an overview of cryptographic hashes and their analysis, check out the [SHA-3 zoo](http://ehash.iaik.tugraz.at/wiki/The_SHA-3_Zoo).